# Laravel - i want to make my sweetalert display first before it redirect to the view

Tags: jquery, laravel, authentication, sweetalert

i try to make my sweetalert to display first before the page redirecting to the intended view, but this doesn't work, when i success login the page redirect to the dashboard page first then show me sweetalert success after that, i want to make the reverse
and i dont know why my error sweetalert doesn't work like my success sweetalert, when i try to put a wrong password or email the error sweetalert doesn't appear and only redirecting the page to my login again witout displaying error sweetalert first.
anyway i use sweetalert version 1 and offline version, i try to search in internet and youtube but nothing works to me :(

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function login()
    {
        return view('auths.login');
    }

    public function postlogin(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::attempt($request->only('username','password'))){
            return redirect('/dashboard')->with('sukses','Login Success...');
        }
        return redirect('/login')->with('eror','Login Failed...');

    } 

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

my main layout :
master.blade.php

```
<script src="/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script>
  @if(Session::has('sukses'))
      swal("Sukses", "{{Session::get('sukses')}}", "success"); // ini untuk sweeralert jika berhasil
  @endif
</script>

<script>
  @if(Session::has('eror'))
      swal("Error", "{{Session::get('eror')}}", "error"); // ini untuk sweeralert jika berhasil
  @endif
</script>
```

my login view
login.blade.php

```
  <form action="/postlogin" method="post">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"  >
          <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block center-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ajax. Firstly you post a login request if response is true show sweetalert and after redirect dashboard

Comment: i don't understand how to use ajax since i still new in coding :(